# How to sideload LineageOS?

Tags: adb, rooting, twrp, fastboot, lineageos

I think I updated `twrp` and `adb` seems to be working:

```
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ adb shell getprop | grep twrp
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ adb shell
shell@htc_m8:/ $ 
shell@htc_m8:/ $ exit
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ adb shell getprop | grep make
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ adb shell getprop | grep model
[ro.aa.modelid]: [0P6B16000]
[ro.chipset.model]: [MSM8974]
[ro.product.model]: [HTC One_M8]
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ adb shell getprop | grep manufacturer
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [HTC]
thufir@doge:~/android$
```

and am, I think, read to proceed with installing `lineageOS` but want to make sure I have the right files and am following the right sequence:

```
thufir@doge:~/android$ adb reboot bootloader
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ fastboot devices
SH4AYWM01306    fastboot
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ fastboot oem get_identifier_token
...
(bootloader)    
(bootloader) < Please cut following message >
(bootloader) <<<< Identifier Token Start >>>>
(bootloader) 8638E3FC990E8996590950FC43B2597A
(bootloader) D3E768DE94AE44F0545422F4F610A2B1
(bootloader) 0D743BEB9D61A214A14203E5DEF9D3A7
(bootloader) 5E519C96B5DA53C4C2C3DA97A3CA584E
(bootloader) B2A07292DD46C6BD13C1F957106DCAF2
(bootloader) 8E9B3C1E660A93B2824622FEB9786109
(bootloader) EAE5E4C7F87D0F2CF41711CC713CAC69
(bootloader) 49ED4E9D2313AB7B8BC7DDF918067039
(bootloader) 448DD51FFD6CA2BEA7F2E03B9E4706F9
(bootloader) 377CE2210B1BCB3E8960B02A970C5430
(bootloader) B404427005C52B6A07A989CC2378C93E
(bootloader) 23D134B3CC30BD33B24B03BBD4C5CE93
(bootloader) 198734886FC83C5DC56044EE0C477786
(bootloader) 037C2393B758EDA5D03B968564561374
(bootloader) 159EA7D89F97C7E8631C5A5E7C1EF967
(bootloader) E64F871FF21B09A0120A302E8B8F6C89
(bootloader) <<<<< Identifier Token End >>>>>
OKAY [  0.069s]
finished. total time: 0.069s
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ fastboot flash recovery twrp.img 
target reported max download size of 1830612992 bytes
sending 'recovery' (21956 KB)...
OKAY [  1.755s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.626s]
finished. total time: 2.382s
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ 
thufir@doge:~/android$ fastboot boot twrp.img 
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  1.741s]
booting...
OKAY [  0.524s]
finished. total time: 2.265s
thufir@doge:~/android$
```

but what does this mean:

> Sideload the LineageOS .zip package:
>
> ```
> On the device, select “Advanced”, “ADB Sideload”, then swipe to begin sideload.
> On the host machine, sideload the package using: adb sideload filename.zip
> ```
>
> (Optionally): If you want to install any additional add-ons, repeat
> the sideload steps above for those packages in sequence. info_outline

I should copy the `zip` file to the phone, then reboot the the phone while pressing the above keys?

Comment: Effectively Sideloading is the same as uploading the LinegeOS zip file to the device and then flash this ZIP file. Therefore sideloading is is uploading and installing a zip file in one command (but the zip file is never stored on the device). Sideloading is typically only available in a custom recovery such as TWRP after you have explicitly enabled it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all... MAKE SURE YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED THE CORRECT ROM FOR YOUR DEVICE..

Steps:

1. Backup important files
2. Connect usb
3. Go to recovery and select wipe
4. select advance
5. select the things you wanna wipe.. except the usb-otg thing
6. After wiping.. go to advance(from home page of twrp)
7. select adb sideload
8. Make sure adb is installed on your pc
9. in cmd(admin) type `adb devices` and check that your phone there
10. Type `adb sideload LineageOS.zip` replace LineageOS.zip with your rom
11. Enjoy LineageOS!!

I'd recommend you to download eelo.. a fork of LineageOS.. It has MicroG which is really awesome.. I'm currently using the same..